# Cakephp 3.0: Multiple matching conditions

Tags: cakephp, matching, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to **daisy-chain `matching()` calls on a query, or find an equivalent way to achieve the same result.** Specifically, here's what I'd like to do:

```
$matchedItemVersion = $this->ItemVersions->find()
    ->where(['version' => $verion])
    ->matching('Items', function($q) use ($ipnCore) {
        return $q->where(['ipn_core' => $ipnCore]);
    })
    ->matching('Items.ItemTypes.ItemSuperGroups', function($q) use ($itemSuperGroupName) {
        return $q->where(['name' => $itemSuperGroupName]);
    })
    ->first()
    ->toArray();
```

This would let me filter my ItemVersions results by two conditions on associated models. However, right now, the second `matching()` call basically overrides the first one, so the first `matching()` call has no effect on the query.

We know that you cannot chain a `matching()` and a `contain()`(https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5109), but is there a way to do it with `matching()`, or a way to get the same result?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can't test it right now, but, try matchception, ie nest the `matching()` calls.

Comment: Thanks @ndm - turns out [from the API (here)](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_matching) that "the query passed to the closure will only accept calling select, where, andWhere and orWhere on it. If you wish to add more complex clauses you can do it directly in the main query." So it would have to be outside the closure it seems...

Comment: The docs are not necessarily up to date, have you actually tried it? I still can't test it, but the core tests show that it is possible: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/7fc4cfe3ae7d4c523331a44e2862bab5c8f44f1e/tests/TestCase/ORM/QueryTest.php#L1844**

Comment: This might be bug. Could you change the order of your `matching()` calls and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @ndm. Interesting, didn't see that test. I'll probably put that as an issue in the repo and see what the devs say. Certainly doesn't work on mine!

Comment: Thanks @Jose Lorenzo - switching the order only switches the conditions that are used, one of the calls is again ignored...

Comment: Can you share the SQL that is generated?